# Copy Windows Phone 7 project

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

I have a windows phone 7 app that is released in the MarketPlace.  What I want to do is create a variant of that app.  So I will have an app that is $1 and an app that is $5.

Is there anyway for me to basically copy the entire project without having to essentially copy and paste everything?

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would stay away from making a copy of fiel if you want to maintain any of the same functionality in both projects going forward. If you don't you'll end up having to change code twice and this can lead to mistakes as well as the overhead of the duplicated task.

Where I've had to do this or similar previously, I've created a new project for the second versino of the app and then added the existing files as linked files (when adding an existing file there's a down arrow on the 'add' button, use this to select 'add as link'). Then in the new project I add additional classes or partial classes to add the extra functionality.
You may also want to consider partial methods for extending functionality or adding empty virtual methods to the stanard project and then subclassing them in the new project and overridding them to add extended functionality.

It should be possible to create multiple projects with very similar and/or shared functionality with no (or almost no) duplication of code.

Comment: Thanks @Matt - I didn't know of the "add as link" feature...  I'll check that out.  That sounds promising for my needs!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you have your solution setup, if you have common libraries etc. I would personally want separate projects for each release of a title, but maybe within the same solution, that way when testing and modifying the shared library changes would apply to both, but when publishing you could choose the appropriate project. You would end up with code duplication, but could lessen it with some re-factoring.

Folder structure would look something like below.

```
RootFolder->
   -ApplicationFree
   -ApplicationPremium
   -SharedLib1
   -SharedLib2
   Application.sln
```

At least this way you are dealing with just one solution per application as opposed to per version.

Comment: I suppose I could just add "existing files" to the new project and just do it that way as well.  I was hoping that there was some sort of "split" feature in VS2010.  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

You could go into C:/Users/YourUserName/My Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/ and then copy and paste your project folder, if you wanted to copy the entire project.